# How to group semantic versioning levels?

Tags: powerquery

I have a document where the semantic versioning goes from 1. to 10. and it goes three levels deep:

ex.

```
1.
1.1
1.2
2.
2.1
2.1.1
2.1.2
3.

...

9.1
9.1.1
10.
```

I tried `=Table.AddColumn(get_prefix, "count_digit", each List.Count(Text.Split([Prefix], ".")))`

but it gives me the count of empty string as well. Where '10. ' is, the count returns 2 when the result should be 1.

I am trying to group these to validate totals to subtotals.

Answer (score 0):

Add column, custom column,

```
= Text.BeforeDelimiter(Text.From([Column1]),".")
```

then group and take rowcount

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(Text.From([Column1]),".")),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Custom"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```